# Is it OK to inject the container into a factory?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I'm using a factory to create different concrete instances of an interface. One of the concrete instances depends on a service that would normally be injected. The life-cycle of the service is managed by the container. In this case is it OK to inject the container into the factory?

Comment: Moar code plox nom nom nom nom nom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would let the container resolve an abstract factory, factory interface, or factory delegate and inject that into consumers instead.

The factory can then take the service as a dependency, which the factory will resolve.

**Update based on comments:**

> If you're injecting the service into the factory, won't the same
>   instance of that service be passed to each object the factory creates?

Yes, each object created by the factory would get the same instance of the service (which is normally what I want). If that's **not** what you want, inject a service factory into the factory. Some containers offer support for automatically resolving factory delegates, so you might be able to inject `Func<IFooService>`.

> But then the life-cycle of the service is bound to the life-cycle of
>   the factory

As @SebastianWeber mentioned in the comments, that is not a restriction of all containers. Also, consider if it matters. You could pick the shortest of the two lifespans and use that for both.

Comment: But then the life-cycle of the service is bound to the life-cycle of the factory

Comment: @JontyMC Says who? As far as I know that is only the case with Castle Windsor's Typed Factory Facilities. Other containers let you define the life-cycle of your service seperately from that of the factory.

Comment: If you're injecting the service into the factory, won't the same instance of that service be passed to each object the factory creates?

Comment: If you don't need extra parameters that you send to the factory inject a `Func<IService>` into your consumers. If you need extra parameters you should have a look at Castle Windsor's [Typed Factory Facilities](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx). There is a port of this feature for Unity in the [TecX project](http://tecx.codeplex.com). See the sources in _TecX.Unity.TypedFactory_ and unit tests in the respective test project.

Answer (score 2):

> In this case is it OK to inject the container into the factory?

It sure is. But *only* if that factory implementation is located inside the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx). If that factory is located in the application itself (in other words, *outside* the Composition Root), you are using the container as a Service Locator, which is [an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) and should be avoided.

Comment: I need to use it outside the composition root. How can I manage the life-cycle via the container when using a factory?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use it outside of the composition root? Typically, your `IMyFactory` interface is defined on an application level, while the `MyFactoryImplementation` is defined inside the composition root. Please show us some code if this doesn't work for you.